# Stack Overflow Careers API

Tags: feature-request, support, jobs, api

SO has an API for most of the site (questions, members, etc.), but I was unable to find any information on a public API for the Careers site. Does one exist? If not, are there any plans for one?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For jobs, our “API” is the RSS feed. You can get a feed of any search of jobs, look for the RSS icon below the search results, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=ruby&l=london):

> [image]

We also have an [API](https://talent.stackoverflow.com/api/try) for employers to post jobs.

What use cases are you hoping for in an API for Careers?

Comment: I am writing an API library that gets job postings for a number of websites that have public APIs.  I've done a number of sites, and decided to look at SO.  In the end, I am simply looking for a way to programmatically get a list of the jobs on the Careers site.  This would include a list of the jobs using the search parameters, but also an API call to get the information on a specific job.  Seems that the RSS feed can give me the jobs, but I don't really see a way to get the job information other than scraping the HTML from the page.

Comment: Looking at the API for employers, it would be great to be able to make an API call and get [this](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/api/demodata?apiAction=Post) back for an individual job.

Comment: But it seems that RSS only contains the most recently posted 25 jobs.It would be great if there's a way to get all the listings easily. (e.g. like [Github Jobs API](https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?page=1)

Comment: Any progress with this?

Comment: Is there an API for resumes too? I'd love to be able to snag all the data in my resume and use it on my personal site.

Comment: +1 for API for resumes. It is not easy to keep in synch: CV, linkedin, and careers profile.

Comment: +1 on that one. I'd love to see an API for updating my profile / resume. I'm using SO careers, LinkedIn, ResearchGate and others, as well as posting my CV as a pdf on my own site. Having to update them all manually is a pain. Often, it just doesn't get done. :-/ So I'm writing some scripts to update my profiles everywhere from a single source.

Comment: what about the user profile API ?

Comment: +1 for API for CV/resume. I'd like to have my details in one place (a plain text file) and then sync that with Stackoverflow, LinkedIn etc. At the moment I don't really use SO Careers because it's too much effort to keep yet another profile in sync.

Comment: I have the same use case as @Skarab except I'm using SO Career as the single source of true for my CV data.  I'd like to have an API around it to auto sync to LinkedIn, AngelList, a concise PDF copy, etc.

Comment: I can get maximum 1000 in the feed

Comment: The RSS feed seems like it sucks - the API for entering jobs has a bunch of fields that don't make it through to the RSS; company name, logo, salary, remote, relocation, etc.

Comment: An API that would allow us to push resume/CV contents into SO would be great - I maintain mine as a [jsonresume](https://jsonresume.org/schema/) document so having an API I could use to sync this to SO Careers would be really good news.

Comment: I was hoping to run analytics on the job postings. Each year we see what techs we're using, but I'd like to see the number of times a specific tech is included in a job post, and what the average pay offerings are, and testing the trends year over year. We can cURL, (or Invoke-WebRequest) it from https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q={}, but I'm not sure SO want's us running so many requests with so much html markup just to parse and tally counts, techs, salaries, etc...